# How to extract immutable from Map(String, List(String)) list using Functional programming in scala

Tags: list, scala, dictionary, collections, functional-programming

```
val filesMap = [/dir/one -> {text1.txt, text2.txt, command.txt}, /dir/two -> {text1.txt, text2.txt, command.txt}, /dir/three -> {text1.txt, text2.txt}} 

val allFiles = filesMap().toList
```

The directory that has the `command.txt` file should be parsed, the rest of them will be ignored. From the above `/dir/three` should be ignored. Then I need to read the `command.txt` which contains commands like the following `Delete: 2` insert two oldest files to the allFiles list. I already have a method for reading `command.txt` file and extract all the commands and it's value to map `commandMap`. For example `commandMap` looks like the following.

```
commandMap = {Delete -> 2, Copy -> 2, Cut -> 2}
```

```
// method that extract commands from commands.txt to the map
def readCommandFile(pathToCommand: String): Map[String, Int] ={
      // som logic to extract list of commands from the text file
}
```

Comment: @Jwvh please let me know if you have any other questions?

Answer (score 1):

```scala
def isCommand: FileStatus => Boolean = f => /* add ur allCommandsInDatFile.contains(numberOfFiles)  */

def getIndex: FileStatus => Int = f => /* add ur Integer.parseInt(allCommandsInDatFile(numberOfFiles) */

fileMap.flatMap { 
  case (_, files) => files.find(isCommand) match { 
    case Some(file) => 
      val index = getIndex(file)
      files.takeRight(index)
    case None => files 
  } 
}
```

Will this solve your problem?

I edited a bit.

Comment: How can I Add multiple Parameter to, here only contains FileStatus => F

Comment: Can you elaborate your `allCommandsInDatFile.contains(numberOfFiles)` ? From my perspective, this just to check if `keep command` lesser than 0 or bigger than list length. you can easily add this logic to `getIndex: FileStatus => Int`.

Comment: I did similar what you have said, if(index != 0) files.takeRight(index) else None, but looks like filter logic is not working.